# rails 4 migration fiels to more then one databse

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, migration

```
postgres_defaults: &postgres_defaults
  adapter: postgresql
  host: localhost

postgres_development: &postgres_development
  <<: *postgres_defaults
  username: postgres
  password:
  database: dev
```

the migration is :

```
# -*- encoding : utf-8 -*-
class CreateTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection "postgres_#{Rails.env}"
    create_table :table_name do |t|
      t.string :status
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :table_name
  end
end
```

but I get this:

```
undefined method `query_options' for nil:NilClass/Users/ohad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@houston/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:218:in `execute'
```

I have added the 'pg' gem to my gemfile.

Comment: Is there a special reason why you put this line `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection "postgres_#{Rails.env}"` in your migration? As far as I understand , your concern is establishment  of connection to the proper db? Rails is in charge with the task , so try removing the line from your migration.

Comment: yes, I have 2 dbs, 1 is mysql and the other is postgres.

Comment: Which one is for development environment? I guess not both of them.

Comment: they are all for development, staging and production

Comment: I would suggest to choose one for development (in your case I can see you prefer Postgres). Did you try to remove this line from your migration file?

Comment: I'm not sure you understand, I need to save to both. is that possible? (migration wise, coding wise, I know it is)